# How to debug 'BUILD FAILED' in Android?

Tags: android

```
D:\Eon_Final_Build\EON_android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:96:13-72 Error:
    Attribute activity#com.facebook.FacebookActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:96:13-72
    is also present at [com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-63 value=(@style/com_facebook_activity_theme).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:92:9-96:75 to override.
See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
:app:processDebugManifest FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.facebook.FacebookActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:96:13-72
    is also present at [com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-63 value=(@style/com_facebook_activity_theme).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:92:9-96:75 to override.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The error actually tells you how to resolve it - "add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:92:9-96:75"

Comment: Please change your post title, it is not clear.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion from the error message?

Answer (score 11):

Facebook new sdk has been released yesterday. Change your facebook sdk dependency as:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me too, Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7):

My gradle line for Facebook SDK was set to

```
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

So it was pulling the latest SDK that came out on 28th Sept (4.16.0). This version is causing this error. To fix this we added the following lines to `<application>` tag in manifest file:

```
tools:node="replace"
tools:replace="android:theme"
```

This seems to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this resolve your bug.

```
<activity
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

**Replace To**

```
<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" />
```

Answer (score 1):

remove activity facebook from your manifest because the last update of gradle merge all activity (lib and sdk ...).

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

or edit version to compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'

Comment: No, you don't remove the (whole) Facebook activity from the Manifest, you just remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` from the activity where FB activity is included/declared.